# Ruby on Rails Tutorial section 6.3 test suite failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, password-encryption

Hi can I ask assistance on this.

I have followed the tutorial and from 6.3 up to 6.3.4. At the end of the chapter I don't seem to be able to have green tests. I receive three errors. I have tried to understand the logic of the errors, and I can't seem to find what I have done incorrectly.

The recurring error that I don't fully understand is 'NoMethodError:undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass'

Searched online with no avail. Your help is much appreciated.

**This is the gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'

group :development, :test do

gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1' 
gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
gem 'spork', '0.9.2'

end

group :development do
gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do

gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
gem 'rb-inotify', '0.8.8' 
gem 'libnotify', '0.5.9'  
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

**The user_spec code**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
     @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password:    
"foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar") 
  end

  subject { @user }

  it  { should respond_to(:name) }
  it  { should respond_to(:email) }
  it  { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it  { should respond_to(:password) }
  it  { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it  { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  it  { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
   before { @user.name = "" }
   it { should_not be_valid }

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = "" }
    it { should_not be_valid }

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user at foo.org example.user@foo. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end
     end
    end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address

       # @user.should be_valid => this should be checked!!!
      end      
    end
  end

   describe "when email address is already taken" do
   before do
    user_with_same_email = @user.dup
    user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
    user_with_same_email.save
   end
   it { should_not be_valid }
end

   describe "when password is not present" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
    end

   describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
  before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end

   describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
   before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
   it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
     it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
  end
end 
end 
end
end
```

**This is the app/models/user**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
 VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

**and finally the errors that I receive when I run the test suite:**

```
.................FFF...................

Failures:

  1) User when name is not present when email is not present when name is too long return value of authenticate method with valid password 
     Failure/Error: it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:100:in `block (7 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User when name is not present when email is not present when name is too long return value of authenticate method with invalid password 
     Failure/Error: let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:104:in `block (7 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:106:in `block (7 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User when name is not present when email is not present when name is too long return value of authenticate method with invalid password 
     Failure/Error: let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:104:in `block (7 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:107:in `block (7 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 6.03 seconds
39 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:100 # User when name is not present when email is not present when name is too long return value of authenticate method with valid password 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:106 # User when name is not present when email is not present when name is too long return value of authenticate method with invalid password 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:107 # User when name is not present when email is not present when name is too long return value of authenticate method with invalid password
```

Comment: Please say what you tried and what parts you are having trouble with.

Comment: Please reduce this to a specific, answerable question. Dumping a bunch of code and expecting us to sort it out is not how this site works. Ask about a specific error (not four errors) or a specific test (not the whole suite).

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your comments. As a newbie or ROR and web development  in general I find difficult to interpret the error message : 'NoMethodError:undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass' did I miss something obvious?

Comment: THAT is a good question. Whenever you see "unidentified method '*x*' for nil:NilClass," whatever *x* was called on, `found_user` in this case, [is nil](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/true-false-and-nil-objects-in-ruby/). Now, go back to where `found_user` is being set and question why the expression `User.find_by_email(@user.email)` is returning nil instead of the value expected.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am thinking about it and the only answer that comes to my mind is that it's because actually there are no record in the database for any user and therefore for any email. But I  have the impression that this is the easiest answer and not the correct one.

Comment: Hi I have found one answer that can apply to my question in the question http://alturl.com/w54nu.
The answer is 'I declared att_accessor for password fields and did not know that the has_secure_password method / bcrypt creates getter / setter method for password as well. Once I commented out the attr_accessor in my model.. all my tests passed.' but I am unsure if this addresses the issue at the root or just gets the tests to pass.

Could you please advise if this is the right way to address the problem or if I need to explore other avenues?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Look at the error message. See how long the test names are? You have several `describe` blocks compounding because you forgot the `end` on each of them. This is probably causing erratic behavior. Fix your indentation and make sure every block in the suite is properly closed. Then try again.

Comment: I want to thank you for your help and your time, I have in fact restarted the whole section and I had the tests to pass just now. As you said that was the main reason as I understood how to properly add 'end' at the end of the blocks.Many thanks again, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failure #1 is easy. Look at the error message. You have a typo.

```
{ should_not_be_valid } != { should_not be_valid }
            ↑                          ↑
```